# Grails Editing Flash Delete Message

Tags: grails

Hi am new at Grails i have implemented a delete action that deleted messages in an inbox,, but now i want to change the flash message to display "2 Messages deleted" not  "Message 4 deleted,Message 5 deleted" if deleting multiple messages. Kindly assist, below is my delete Action

def delete() {

```
    def messageInstance = Message.get(params.id)

    // render error if no message found
    if (!messageInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'message.label', default: 'Message'), params.id])
        redirect(action: "phone")
    } else {
        // get the device that we are deleting from
        //specify phoneNumber so as to delete the device by phoneNumber
        def device = MessagingDevice.findByPhoneNumber(params.phoneNumber)

        // invoke deleteFromDevice on domain object, which returns true if successful
        if (messageInstance.deleteFromDevice(device)) {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'message.label', default: 'Message'), params.id])
            redirect(action: "phone", params:[phoneNumber:params.phoneNumber])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if (messageInstance.deleteFromDevice(device)) {
    int count= messageInstance.count()
    flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [count, message(code: 'message.label')])
    redirect(action: "phone", params:[phoneNumber:params.phoneNumber])
   }

Comment: Come to realise that count() returns the total number of row of the domain table  thought it would return the number of messages after deleting?? Any advice??

Answer (score 0):

in code:

```
int count = 5 //number of deleted messages

flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.messages', args: [message(code: 'messages.label', default: 'Messages'), count])
```

in messages.properties:

```
messages.label=Messages
default.deleted.messages={1} {0} deleted
```

Comment: Why set the number of deleted messages to 5??

Comment: That's just an example, you set it yourself.

Comment: shud count be a function, that i able to count the number of deleted message because if i set a default number dont think it will work???

Comment: Something like int count=messageInstance.count()

Comment: inorder to get the number of deleted msgs ?

Comment: I thought you are asking how to edit the flash message. The logic behind deleting mesagges is up to you and is not in scope of this question. grails.org

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
    def device = MessagingDevice.findByPhoneNumber(params.phoneNumber)

    // invoke deleteFromDevice on domain object, which returns number of objects deleted
    def count = messageInstance.deleteFromDevice(device)
    if (count) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'message.deleted.label', default: '{0} Messages deleted'), count])
        redirect(action: "phone", params:[phoneNumber:params.phoneNumber])
    }
```

and in your messages.properties

```
message.deleted.label={0} deleted
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look up the `default.deleted.message` key in your `messages.properties` you'll see it looks like

```
default.deleted.message={0} {1} deleted
```

Simply add a new line with the key and value you want.

```
inbox.deleted.message={0} messages deleted
```

and use it in your controller

```
flash.message = message(code: 'inbox.deleted.message', args: [deletedMessageCount])
```

Of course, you'll need to define a value for `deletedMessageCount` before using it.