# Grails the Displaying the Number of deleted Messages in a Flash Message

Tags: grails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grails Editing Flash Delete Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192692/grails-editing-flash-delete-message)

Hi,
I am new at Grails I have implemented a delete action that deleted messages in an inbox, but now I want to change the flash message to display **2 Messages deleted** not **Message 4 deleted,Message 5 deleted** if deleting multiple messages. Kindly assist, below is my delete Action

```
def delete() {

    def messageInstance = Message.get(params.id)

    // render error if no message found
    if (!messageInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'message.label', default: 'Message'), params.id])
        redirect(action: "phone")
    } else {
        // get the device that we are deleting from
        //specify phoneNumber so as to delete the device by phoneNumber
        def device = MessagingDevice.findByPhoneNumber(params.phoneNumber)

        // invoke deleteFromDevice on domain object, which returns true if successful
        if (messageInstance.deleteFromDevice(device)) {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'message.label', default: 'Message'), params.id])
            redirect(action: "phone", params:[phoneNumber:params.phoneNumber])
        }
    }
}
```